# Why is my Binary Tree iterator coming to a halt?

Tags: java, tree

While attempting to traverse a binary-tree in an inorder fashion, it prints the root, the rightmost children and then stops. Something is clearly wrong, and I am having difficulties wrapping my head around this, as I am new to Tree-structures. What am I doing wrong?

**Main**:

```
while (tree.iterator().hasNext())
    System.out.println(tree.iterator().next());
```

**Iterator**:

```
public Iterator<T> iterator() {
  Iterator<T> it = new Iterator<T>() {

    Node<T> next = root;

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
      return next != null;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
      if (!hasNext())
        throw new NoSuchElementException();

      System.out.println("Returning data");
      T r = next.data;

      if (next.right != null) {
        next = next.right;
        while (next.left != null)
          next = next.left;

      } else while (true) {
        if (next.parent == null) {
          next = null;
          return r;
        }
        if (next.parent.left == next) {
          next = next.parent;
          return r;
        }
        next = next.parent;
      }
      return r;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

  };
  return it;
}
```

**Output:**

```
242
275
279
283
```

242 is the root of the tree. 
242.left = 33
242.right = 283

**Update 1:**

**Tree:**

```
242
|33
||29
|||25
||||NULL
||||NULL
|||NULL
||74
|||70
||||66
|||||NULL
|||||NULL
||||NULL
|||115
||||111
|||||107
||||||NULL
||||||NULL
|||||NULL
||||156
|||||152
||||||148
|||||||NULL
|||||||NULL
||||||NULL
|||||197
||||||193
|||||||NULL
|||||||NULL
||||||238
|||||||234
||||||||NULL
||||||||NULL
|||||||NULL
|283
||279
|||275
||||NULL
||||NULL
|||NULL
||NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to start on the right side of the root, before going to the left-most child. So you miss the whole left part to start with.

You should initialize `next` with the left-most child, not the root.

**Update:** You can do that in an initialization block, like this:

```
Iterator<T> it = new Iterator<T>() {

    Node<T> next;

    {
        next = root;
        while (next.left != null)
            next = next.left;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return next != null;     
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "choose an order"?

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood the "inorder" term here ;)

Comment: Any idea where I should do that? It is obviously a job for the anonymous Iterator-class, but where? There exists no reference to "the leftmost node", so I gotta do a `while (next.left!=null) next = next.left;` thing.

Comment: Yes, you have to do that in the constructor. Redefine it, or add an initialization block with just `{}`.

Comment: That was my initial idea, but i am not allowed to define a constructor for some reason. `public Iterator<T>() {` and `public Iterator() {` are both invalid

Comment: Oh, right. You'll have to use an initialization block. I edited my post.

Comment: Wow, I have never "just a couple of curlybraces" since I started with Java. It runs perfectly, thanks so much :)

Comment: You're welcome ;) This kind of init block is often not heard of by many people ^^